# Incorrectly pivoting table after JOINing?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

```
SELECT

  GROUP_CONCAT(if(meta_summary = 'content', content, NULL)) AS content, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(meta_summary = 'supplemental', content, NULL)) AS supplemental,
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(meta_summary = 'heading', content, NULL)) AS heading,

cms_pages.meta_filename as filename

FROM
cms_pages

INNER JOIN cms_collection

ON

cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT('%', cms_pages.page_id,  '/heading%' )
OR cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT('%', cms_pages.page_id,  '/content%' )
OR cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT('%', cms_pages.page_id,  '/supplemental%' )

INNER JOIN

cms_content ON cms_collection.collection_id = cms_content.collection_id

WHERE
site_id = 51

GROUP BY
cms_pages.page_id
```

Schema *BEFORE* the GROUP BY:

```
Filename        Content

pageA           (Heading Content)
pageA           (Content)
pageA           (Supplemental Content)
```

Desired rule-set:

```
Filename       Heading            Content          Supplemental
pageA          (Heading Content) (Content)         (Supp. Content)
```

I tried reading http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78 but can't figure out why this isn't working for me - it seems like it's incorrectly group concatenating the rows.. some are right and some look like they incorrectly merged with content from another page. Could this be because I need to do a subquery with the group concat because of all my joins?

**Update #1: Created a sqlfiddle @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe3e3/1, but it actually works there.. either**

a) I didn't recreate it properly 
b) Maybe it's NaviCat that's messing up the results, though I doubt it

**Update #2:** Found the reason - it was because the LIKE I was using was (rightfully) matching substrings, so '2/content' would match '22/content' and so forth.

How should I alter my INNER JOIN on cms_collection in an efficient manner to do an exact match?

Comment: at the moment I can't but the content for the "content" is HTML, headings are straight up text, supplementary is HTML too.., if that has any significance.. ill try to put up an example tomorrow.

Comment: Ok. I figured out why this happened - because the LIKE I was using was  (rightfully) matching substrings, so '2/content' would match '22/content' and so forth. How should I alter my INNER JOIN on cms_collection in an efficient manner to do an exact match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the wildcard from the *start* of the LIKE string-matching join condition, like so:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(meta_summary = 'content', content, NULL)) AS content, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(meta_summary = 'supplemental', content, NULL)) AS supplemental,
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(meta_summary = 'heading', content, NULL)) AS heading,
  cms_pages.meta_filename as filename
FROM cms_pages
INNER JOIN cms_collection ON
  cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT(cms_pages.page_id, '/heading%')
  OR cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT(cms_pages.page_id, '/content%')
  OR cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT(cms_pages.page_id, '/supplemental%')
INNER JOIN
  cms_content ON cms_collection.collection_id = cms_content.collection_id
WHERE
  site_id = 53
GROUP BY
  cms_pages.page_id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e426/2).